# Xamarin StreamWriter

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Could you hep me with a doubt I have?

I have an embedded resource text file, and when I try to use a streamWriter to write on it, I get this error: "A System.ArgumentException was thrown. Can not write to stream."

This is the code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "SuperMimo2.Products.txt";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.WriteLine(txtLines.Text);
}
```

Could you tell me what can I do?

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You cannot write to an embedded resource. Not what you think this would do.

Comment: Instead of an embedded resource what Build action should I set the file to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android and iOS packages/bundles are signed and not writable.  To write to a file, you have to use one of the appropriate file system folders provided by the OS.

for iOS, refer to this guide:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

for Android, you can do

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, my_file_name);
```

If you want to include a file with your app and write to it, you will first need to include it as an Asset in your app's bundle.  Then you will need to copy it to a writable folder in order to make any changes to it.

```
// read the data from the Asset
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
    {
        content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
    }

// get a writable file path
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, "write_asset.txt");

// write the data to the writable path - now you can read and write it
File.WriteAllText(filename, content);
```

Comment: what can I do now? The program writes on the file during its executation, but after that, the file doesn't save what has been writen.

Comment: how are you checking the contents of the file?  Are you using some file explorer tool?  Or checking it by running the app again?  Or are you reading the content back immediately after writing it?

Comment: I'm using the "watch" tool.

Comment: And when the program finishes I open the writer_asset file, and it is empty.

Comment: what is the build action the files should have?

Comment: could you try doing all this , and check if you can put this working?

Comment: Are you running this on a device or an emulator?  Exactly how are you "opening" the file to verify it?  Is this UTF-8 text?  If it is not, read the docs for WriteAllText() for optional parameters to specify the encoding.

Comment: on an emulator. In xamarin, I open the folder assets, and in there, I found write_assets.txt, I double-click in it, to open the file

Comment: When you run in an emulator it is writing the file inside of the EMULATOR'S FILE SYSTEM.  It is not writing it back to the folder where your project's source code is located.  You need to look at the emulator's file system to see the file.  As I asked before, please take the time to READ THE DOCS from Xamarin and Android on working with the file system.  It seems like there are some very basic concepts you do not understand.